# "invalid" results from NSArray arraywithcontentsoffile

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist

I have these plist files that I have used without problem, converting them into arrays with either arraywithcontentsoffile or initwithcontentsoffile. All of a sudden it stopped working, when I inspect the arrays in the debugger i get this as elements.

```
" Printing description of [0]:(<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']'error: 1 errors parsing expression>"
```

Does anyone have a clue? strange thing is that the command has completely stopped working. I even made a new project using a new file and it still throws me this error.

This is what i do:

```
NSArray *name = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

and the plist is just a simple plist of type array and element-type string

Comment: How do you "inspect" them in the debugger? From the looks of the error it just looks like it doesn't like using subscript literal syntax...

Comment: `NSLog` `name` what do you get? Is the array `nil`? What statement is causing the error? Verify that the file exists, open the file with a text editor and verify that it is a valid plist.

Comment: @Mani It is not JSON, it is a plist which is XML.

Comment: @Zaph he's trying to inspect it in the debugger

Comment: @Rich how? a simple `po name` hopefully.

Comment: by inspect i mean i hover over the array when sitting on a breakpoint, i gives me a few elements, each containing this error

Comment: Best guess: the plist is invalid. Verify that the file exists, open the file with a text editor and verify that it is a valid plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try it...

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YOURPLIST" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSArray *playDictionariesArray = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"Here is the Dict %@",playDictionariesArray);
```

or you can use following also

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a very old Xcode bug. Do an NSLog dump to see if the values are there. This inspector doesn't function even as late as Xcode 6.1! I'll make a radar.